# JavaScript not Working in ASP .Net MVC Entity framework

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I am trying to wire up a button with some API using the click method but its not working. The JS on the rest of my web site is working fine but this does not seem to like me.. P.S I am new to asp .net and I am working using a tutorial so if anything is done in a certain way its because that's how its done in tutorial. here is my code of the page that is creating the problem,

```
@model IEnumerable<GigHub.Models.Gig>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<ul class="gigs">
    @foreach(var gig in Model)
    {
        <li>
            <div class="date">
                <div class="month">
                    @gig.DateTime.ToString("MMM")
                </div>
                <div class="day" style="background:#f7f7f7;color:#333;font-size:20px;padding:6px 12px;">
                    @gig.DateTime.ToString("d ")
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <span class="artist">
                    @gig.Artist.Name
                </span>
                <span class="genre">
                    @gig.Genre.Name
                </span>
                <button data-gig-id="@gig.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right js-toggle-attendence">Going?</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("js-toggle-attendence").click(function (event) {
                var button = $(event.target);
                $.post("/api/attendances", { gigId: button.attr("data-gig-id") }).done(function () {
                    button.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Going");
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert("Error Occured!");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}`
```

this is the div that seems the problem

```
<div class="details">
                    <span class="artist">
                        @gig.Artist.Name
                    </span>
                    <span class="genre">
                        @gig.Genre.Name
                    </span>
                    <button data-gig-id="@gig.Id" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right js-toggle-attendence">Going?</button>
                </div>
```

and this is the script

```
@section scripts
    {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("js-toggle-attendence").click(function (event) {
                    var button = $(event.target);
                    $.post("/api/attendances", { gigId: button.attr("data-gig-id") }).done(function () {
                        button.removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-info").text("Going");
                    }).fail(function () {
                        alert("Error Occured!");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    }`
```

Comment: Can you see any errors within the console? Is javascript included within the view?

Comment: i had errors like libhelp.js not found and i added those missing refrences but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

There is a "." missing in your JQuery selector for the class, it should be:

```
$(".js-toggle-attendence").click(function (event) {
```

Instead of:

```
$("js-toggle-attendence").click(function (event) {
```

Comment: Cool, can you set my response as a correct answer? Thx

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, if you want to mention a class, use the notation .

If you want to mention the elementID, use notation #

In your code, you missed the notation . in the line

```
$("js-toggle-attendence")
```

To correct it, change to

```
$(".js-toggle-attendence")
```